# Android Camera Intent saving file twice / how to avoid

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I am using the easy camera intent for taking simple pictures in Android as follows:

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( photo );
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
camera.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
this.startActivityForResult(camera, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

The problem is: The file is saved twice

- Once when the picture is actually taken (then it is saved to the gallery directory)
- Once when the user "accepts" the picture (then it is saved to outputFileUri)

Although I really cant imagine this fact I already read about that the creating of those duplicate files cannot be avoided. **But** if not, is there a possibility to get the path of the picture in the gallery directory to delete it by my app?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you guys know, I did some research and it is actually not a good idea to solve it like this - unfortunately.

Nevertheless you can do a very easy SurfaceView-Camera-Activity which will only save the data you are telling it to.